# Google Chrome: can't get current tab's url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have the following function in my chrome extension's background.js to get the current tab's url:

```
function getCurrentUrl() {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0]
        var keys = []
        for(var key in tab) keys.push(key + '-' + tab[key])
        alert(keys.join(', '))
    })
}
```

But, the alert dialog shows me:

```
active-true, height-456, highlighted-true, id-301, incognito-false, index-6, pinned-false, selected-true, status-complete, width-717, windowId-262
```

The 'tab' object doesn't seem to have a url property, as suggested by other answers on SO. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the url, add the following to manifest.json:

"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]

source: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html